# Calculating P-Value of a Z-Score without using Z-Table

Tags: normal-distribution, python, p-value, z-score

I couldn't find any videos or documentation that shows how to calculate p-value of a z-score without using z-table. Isn't it possible or is it that hard?

I know i can use scipy to get that information but how can we calculate without needing them?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly it's possible. After all, people need to calculate the tables in the first place.

Recall the definition of a $p$ value. Given a value $z$, the $p$ value is defined as the tail probability of the [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) beyond $z$:

$$ p \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx. $$

This is an improper integral that needs to be [numerically evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF). Or, more precisely, approximated.

Comment: Stephan thank you. But is there a python code for this equation? I'm not that great with mathematical formulas :)

Comment: I don't speak Python, sorry. You might want to look through [the "Python" and "normal-distribution" tags at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%2bnormal-distribution?tab=Votes). Most of which will likely point you at scipy. You might want to post a question there and explain why you don't want to use scipy.

Comment: @Don Coder: two-sided test ```scipy.stats.norm.sf(z)*2```; one-sided test: ```scipy.stats.norm.sf(z)``` (Stephan's answer)